# Samba and Groups (Windows Host, VM Linux Guest)

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, samba

Ok I've been reading about Samba shares etc. for the past few days, I still cannot get it to work.

I've gotten a public share and a private user share to work, but not a group share.

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    map to guest = bad user 
    #state directory = /var/lib/samba
    #usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares

[public]
    comment = public share
    path = /srv/abc/public
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    ready only = no
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 

[private]
    comment = private share
    path = /srv/abc/private
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    security = user
    valid users = test
    ready only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 

[mygroup]
    comment = mygroup server files
    path = /srv/mygroup
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    security = user
    valid users = @mygroup
    force group = mygroup
    ready only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 
    force create mode = 0777
    force security mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
```

I done the following to add a user an d group.

```
sudo useradd karl
sudo passwd karl
sudo groupadd mygroup
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup karl
sudo smbpasswd -a karl
sudo mkdir /srv/mygroup
sudo chmod 777 /srv/mygroup
sudo chgrp mygroup /srv/mygroup
```

I still can't log into it via my windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days I found this lovely post: https://serverfault.com/questions/549289/the-network-folder-specified-is-currently-mapped-using-a-different-user-name-and Windows cannot handle more than one username per server.

You create one account and adjust all the permissions to everything
Go into the Windows hosts file and create several hostnames that point towards the same ip (effectivly luring Windows)